# LabView SubVI terminal with variable data type

Tags: types, type-conversion, labview, variant, typecast-operator

I would like to create a `SubVI` that has an output terminal with a variable data type. Outside the `SubVI` the terminal will be connected to a `Type Cast`. I do not want to use the `Variant` as data type.

**Block diagram**

[image: VI block diagram]

Is this possible and if yes how can it be done?

Comment: You can try using polymorphic VI.

Comment: @Khachik: Using a polymorphic VI is not possible if you need to choose the data type at run-time.

Comment: Where is the requirement regarding the run-time in the question?

Comment: It is not strictly necessary to change the datatype at run-time. It would make the code a lot prettier though. In the actual code I am using ‘Variant to Data’ and not ‘Type Cast’ but it needs a type too. I will work around the problem by using constants. I do not think it is even possible to change the type of a typecast at run-time because I think it is a polymorphic VI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. There is only one data type that is capable of carrying all data types. That is Variant. I don't know why you don't want to use it, but that's your only option. Type Cast is only for castable types (i.e. numerics and a few other limited cases like casting a string to an array of bytes).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Flatten to String** VI and than **Unflatten from String** VI (instead of **Type Cast**).

Why do you want to avoid the Variant data type?

Comment: The example above is simplified. Actually I am using `Variant`. The problem occurs where the data is being converted from `Variant` back to multiple different generic data types. I would like to pass a data type (which one should be determined during run-time) to the `type` terminal of the `Variant To Data` VI.

Comment: I don't know the details of your case, so I could be wrong, but I have the impression that Classes could help you a lot here.

Comment: Yes, that is very likely the case! In almost every other language I would have used object oriented programming. I know, that this is possible in LabView too. I do not know why but in LabView I never use object oriented programming.

Comment: If you are familiar with OOP then Labview OOP should be (almost) straightforward. Here's a starting point: http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3573/en/

Answer (score 0):

I do type convert all the time. If I need multiple solutions under program control I use a case selector and create an instance of each type needed. The case selector also offers multiple outputs for data types.